# Adding TextView dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a EditText and a Button in my activity xml. What i wanted to do is that on clicking the button the text from the EditText should get displayed in a TextView above the EditText.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:hint="@string/hint_message"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

and this is my sendMessage()

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message=editText.getText().toString();       
    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout01);
    TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.setText(message);
    layout.addView(text);
}
```

When i click the button, nothing happens. Nothing at all.
Any idea why this is not working? I'm pretty new to Android development.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your LinearLayout tag.

```
android:id="@+id/linear"
```

And change your sendMessage method to following

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message=editText.getText().toString();       
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
TextView text=new TextView(this);
text.setText(message);
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(text);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You must have a `TextView` above your `EditText` and set its property `android:visibility="gone"`.

Now, when you want to show your text in that `TextView`, at that time. do `getText()` to get text from `EditText` and set that text using `setText()` for your `TextView` and at the same time for your `TextView`, do `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

like,

```
String text = editText.getText();
textView.setText(text);
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your XML to following.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/linear"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""
/>

<EditText 
android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:hint="@string/hint_message"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_send"
android:text="@string/button_text"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

And now your sendMessage() should look like this one.

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message=editText.getText().toString();       
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
text.setText(message);
```

}

Comment: will this work if i wanted to display new TextView every time I click the button??

Comment: for new TextView every time, My first answer will work in that way. this will set new text on previous text view every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `LayoutParams` (wrap_content/match_parent) for your new View :

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);

text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    

text.setText(message);
layout.addView(text);
```